# How to avoid multiple declarations in angularoutes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

My App module

```
/* dependency Modules */
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

/* router configuration */
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routes';

/* components */
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

/* project Modules */
import { subscriptionModule } from '../components/subscription/subscription.module';

/* app declaration */
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    subscriptionModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

My Route Config

```
/* dependency modules */
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

/* subscription */
/*components */
import { subscriptionComponent } from '../components/subscription/subscription.component';
import { subscriptionMenuComponent } from './../components/subscription/includes/menu/subscriptionMenu.component';
import { subscriptionSubscribeComponent } from './../components/subscription/includes/subscribe/subscriptionSubscribe.component';

export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'subscription', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'subscription', component: subscriptionComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: subscriptionMenuComponent },
      { path: 'subscribe', component: subscriptionSubscribeComponent },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig, { useHash: true }),
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My Subscription Module

```
/* dependency modules */
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

/* components */
import { subscriptionComponent } from './subscription.component';
import { subscriptionHeaderComponent } from './header/subscriptionHeader.component';
import { subscriptionMenuComponent } from './includes/menu/subscriptionMenu.component';
import { subscriptionSubscribeComponent } from './includes/subscribe/subscriptionSubscribe.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    subscriptionComponent,
    subscriptionHeaderComponent,
    subscriptionMenuComponent,
    subscriptionSubscribeComponent
  ]
})

export class subscriptionModule { }
```

In my code, I already imported components in the Subscription module, do I have to re-import it in the router configurtation. I am totally new to angular 2 can someone tell me that what I have done is correct . the pages are loading correctly, but is there any possibleway to reduce the imports.

Answer (score 0):

- In `ngModule` you must have to import all the components which you are using in that module
- but also you must have to import all those component's which are used in routing.
- But in case of lazy loading only no need to import components in the routing file and in module as well.

Comment: yeah, Ok. In subscription module, I have imported all the components for the subscription. why can't I directly import that module, instead of the components? Any way to do it. @Pardeep Jain